# How to extract the text 209.520 within a span as per the HTML through Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm doing an automation with selenium and I'm trying to take the value that is inside a span label. How can I do it? I already tried with getText() but prints a null

This is the line in the HTML

```
<span class="visible-xs" data-bind="html: PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol">209.520</span>
```

I need to take the number 99.520. I already made the correct xpath that finds it but how do I extract that value?

Thanks for your help.

The xpath if it brings several objects but what I need is to get that value,

this is the xpath that I use

```
//div[@class='totalPrice']/span[@data-bind='html: PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol']
```

And this is the code HTML

```
<div class="flightPriceContainer notranslate">
                                <div class="totalPrice">
                                    <span class="hidden-xs" data-bind="html: Price">COP 209.520</span>
                                    <span class="visible-xs" data-bind="html: CurrencySymbol">COP</span>
                                    <span class="visible-xs" data-bind="html: PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol">209.520</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the source code you are trying?

Comment: If there must be a possibility that more than one node is matching with your xpath. Place the HTML here.

Comment: you can also get null if this element placed in a different iframe. w/o your code its really hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to extract the text **209.520** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be visible and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String labelText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.flightPriceContainer.notranslate > div.totalPrice > span.visible-xs[data-bind$='PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  String labelText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='flightPriceContainer notranslate']/div[@class='totalPrice']/span[@class='visible-xs' and contains(@data-bind,'PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution using lxml but the xpath should be identical in Java.

```
html = '<span class="visible-xs" data-bind="html: PriceWithoutCurrencySymbol">99.520</span>'
print(''.join(lxml.html.fromstring(html).xpath('//span//text()')))
```